# Указал checkbox выбор только одной опции, всё работает. Но помимо этого у меня есть другие чекбоксы, только с другими name, как написать сразу всем?

Tags: javascript, html

html код

```
<ul>
          <li>
            <label for="priceChoice1">від 1 до 100 грн</label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="priceChoice1"
              name="prices"
              value="100hrv"
            />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="priceChoice2">від 100 до 500 грн </label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="priceChoice2"
              name="prices"
              value="500hrv"
            />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="priceChoice3">від 500 до 1000 грн</label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="priceChoice3"
              name="prices"
              value="1000hrv"
            />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="priceChoice4">від 1000 та більше</label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="priceChoice4"
              name="prices"
              value="morehrv"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Автор -->
      <div class="author">
        <h2>Автор</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="authorChoice1">Стивен Кінг</label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="authorChoice1"
              name="authors"
              value="King"
            />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="authorChoice2">Вільям Шекспір </label>
            <input
              class="input-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              id="authorChoice2"
              name="authors"
              value="Shekspir"
            />
          </li>
```

Код js для выбора одного чекбокс из нескольких с одним name.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("genres");
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].onchange = checkboxHandler;
}

function checkboxHandler(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked && inputs[i] !== this) {
      inputs[i].checked = false;
    }
```

}
}

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("genres")` замени на `[...document.querySelectorAll('.input-checkbox')]`

Comment: Спасибо, работает, пока не совсем усвоил и понимаю все методы document.

Comment: На здоровье! :)